# turn cofibration to fibre bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Suppose $X$ a CW complex, Y its subcomplex, $T$ is any parameter space.

If we have map:
$Y \to X \to X/Y$, the first map is inclusion and the second map is collapsing map, if we apply all spaces with mapping functor obtaining:

$Map(X/Y,  T) \to Map(X, T) \to Map(Y, T)$.

I wonder if this sequence of mappings  a fibre bundle?

I'm reading the Geometry of Four Manifolds by Donaldson, he states a special case for $X$ a simply-connected 4 manifold, $Y$ its $2$-cells, $T$ the classfying space $BG$ and he only consider a connected components of $Map(S, BG)$, here $S$ can be $X, Y, X/Y$.

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Your title says “fibration” but your body says “fiber bundle”. These are by no means the same thing!

Comment: @KevinArlin Sorry, I just use the same word as the book Geometry of Four Manifolds by Donaldson, he say “mapping functor turns cofibration into fibration” but he also mention the fibre and base of such fibration.

Comment: @KevinArlin I think maybe he indeed use mapping functor to turn the cofibration $Y \to X$ at first and use others way to prove it in fact a fibre bundle with fibre Map(X/Y, BG), but I feel confused about his words.

Comment: It is true when $X$ is locally compact $T_2$ and when $Map(-,-)$ denote the space of *pointed* maps. It is false if using unpointed maps.

Comment: @Tyrone Hello, could you give me a reference about it? Thanks!

Comment: See Proposition 3.2 [here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~tcutler/pdf/Fibrations%20I.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Now I believe this general case is not true.

Suppose we have pair of space $(S^n, D^{n+1})$ and $T$ is some space with nontrivial $n$th homotopy group.

Now $Map(S^n, T)$ consists of all nontrivial equivalent classes represent the nontrivial homotopy group of $T$ but $Map(D^{n+1}, T)$ only consists of the map which homotopy to trivial map, so for this case it fails to be a fibre bundle.

Maybe the fibre mentioned in this book is just the preimage of a fix based point.